# How can I add controls to Skins in win32 API

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have created a skin in VC++ through the win32 API. Now I want to add controls to the skins. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using following code, its a button with bit map image.

```
hButton = CreateWindow ("BUTTON", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP |                        WS_TABSTOP |WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | BS_BITMAP| BS_FLAT|EDGE_SUNKEN,
            175, 135, B_width1, B_height1, hWnd, (HMENU)IDB_BUTTON_WOPEN, 
            ((LPCREATESTRUCT) lParam)->hInstance, NULL);

/* Set the button image */
SendMessage(hButton[7], BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP,
(LPARAM)LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IMG_BITMAP7)));
```